# cygwin lcov genhtml: ERROR: cannot create directory ?

Tags: cygwin, lcov

I am executing the following command, which is resulting in the error below. I have chmod 777 to all directories involved. The css and image files are written successfully, but the html file(s) is not getting generated. What am I do worng?

```
perl genhtml -o coverage jsTestDriver.conf-coverage.dat

Reading data file jsTestDriver.conf-coverage.dat
Found 4 entries.
No common filename prefix found!
Writing .css and .png files.
Generating output.
mkdir: cannot create directory '': No such file or directory
genhtml: ERROR: cannot create directory !
```

Comment: The genhtml script is trying to create a directory with the name of an empty string ("").  This can't exist, so it's failing, nothing to do with permissions (perhaps not the most helpful message).  I'm not familiar with the script so I can't say why or how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. A variable on the perl file is not getting set correctly, so I set it to a string, which suppressed the error. However, the counts in the html files are empty.

Comment: The source files in jsTestDriver.conf-coverage.dat contained a Windows drive 'C:'. ':' are used to specify name, value pairs in lcov. This was causing the script to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this cross platform alternative to lcov genhtml - requires no cygwin. http://code.google.com/p/jgenhtml/